# SQLite3 storing String which contains only numbers

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

I have to run a very simple query like this in SQLite3.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tblPhoneList(Phone, PeopleId, StorageType) VALUES('+91912345789', '1','1');
```

But whatever I do, the number is stored as 91912345789. The + prefix is ignored.
The field `Phone` is a `String`. Why does it ignore the + prefix?
Is there anyway to avoid this?

P.S. This code is run inside Android

EDIT:
This is the schema of the table

```
CREATE TABLE tblPhoneList(Phone STRING PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE, StorageT
ype INTEGER, PeopleId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(PeopleId) references tblPeople(id));
```

Comment: SQLite is notoriously lax about types.  It sounds like they're "duck-typing" the string into a number and back again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<**UPDATE**> from [the manual](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname):

> the declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not TEXT

so please change the type of this column to `TEXT`, and you should be done.  </**UPDATE END**>

what is the type of your `Phone` column (try `PRAGMA table_info (tblPhoneList)`)?. if it is `TEXT` (or `BLOB`), you shouldn't have any problems - just tried this here. if it is `INTEGER` or `REAL`, you should convert it to `TEXT` - you cannot expect an `INTEGER` or `REAL` column to store the `+` string.

for all the details, see [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: I checked the type. It is String. I have posted the schema here.

Answer (score 2):

It's text! SQLite only supports Integer, Text, Real and BLOB.

Comment: It is String, I have posted the Schema.

Comment: Lol :) SQLite will glob just about any term, such as string, into the closest match (text, integer, real, blob). see "affinity" section of this: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 1):

the field Phone in your DB cannot be a String, you'd better check it, TEXT or VARCHAR may work. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tblPhoneList(Phone, PeopleId, StorageType) VALUES('\+91912345789', '1','1');
```

Comment: I tried that. It just stores '\+91912345789' as it is. With the slash.

Comment: Okay. you have to clarify one thing.i.e you are passing a string as query? if yes then try this: "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tblPhoneList(Phone, PeopleId, StorageType) VALUES('"+"\+"+"91912345789', '1','1');"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies.
I changed the type `String` (yes, String type IS supported) to `Varchar(32)` and this error magically goes off. Looks like `String` type is poorly supported in here.

Comment: you might consider accepting the answer (other than your own) that brought you there.